# Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting "Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3)." while inserting entities in database with spring data JPA. Below is my code:

```
package com.shree.testjpa.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity @Table(name = "city")
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class City implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;

}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity @Table(name = "company")
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;
}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity @Table(name = "person")
@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "country_name")
    private String countryName;
    
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_city_company", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(table = "person", name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(table = "person", name = "country_name", referencedColumnName = "country_name", insertable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(table = "city", name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(table = "city", name = "country_name", referencedColumnName = "country_name", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<City> stayed;

    
}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa.repo;

import com.shree.testjpa.entity.City;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long>{

}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa.repo;

import com.shree.testjpa.entity.Company;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long>{

}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa.repo;

import com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{

}
```

==

```
package com.shree.testjpa;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.shree.testjpa.entity.City;
import com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person;
import com.shree.testjpa.repo.CityRepository;
import com.shree.testjpa.repo.CompanyRepository;
import com.shree.testjpa.repo.PersonRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepo personRepo;

    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    CompanyRepository compoCompanyRepository;
    
    public void initTables() {
        
        //List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //cityList.add(new City(0, "Gargoti", "India"));
        //cityList.add(new City(0, "Delhi", "India"));
        //cityList.add(new City(0, "Kolhapur", "India"));
        //cityList.add(new City(0, "Pune", "India"));

        List<City> cityList = cityRepository.findAll();

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new Person(0, "Shrirang", 25, "India", cityList));
        //people.add(new Person(0, "Bhagwat", 25, "India", cityList.subList(1,2)));


        personRepo.saveAll(people);
    }

    public void printTables(){
        System.out.println(personRepo.findAll());
    }

}
```

===

```
package com.shree.testjpa;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestJpaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestJpaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //testService.printTables();
        testService.initTables();
    }


}
```

==
application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# drop n create table, good for testing, comment this in production
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

==

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.shree.testjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-jpa</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

==
**MySql SQL with sample data:
=======**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `City`;

CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


LOCK TABLES `City` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (1,'Gargoti','India'),(2,'Kolhapur','India');

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Company`;

CREATE TABLE `Company` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


LOCK TABLES `Company` WRITE;

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Person`;

CREATE TABLE `Person` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


LOCK TABLES `Person` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `Person` VALUES (8,'Shrirang',25,'India');

UNLOCK TABLES;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `person_city_company`;

CREATE TABLE `person_city_company` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `city_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


LOCK TABLES `person_city_company` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `person_city_company` VALUES (1,8,1,-1,'India'),(2,8,2,-1,'India');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

==
ER Digram
[image: ER Digram]

==
Exception:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2021-11-26 13:28:02.696  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.shree.testjpa.TestJpaApplication     : Starting TestJpaApplication using Java 11.0.11 on admins-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 3971 (/Volumes/CodeDrive/authmvp/authmvpwps/test-jpa/target/classes started by skumbhar in /Volumes/CodeDrive/authmvp/authmvpwps/test-jpa)
2021-11-26 13:28:02.697  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.shree.testjpa.TestJpaApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-26 13:28:03.049  INFO 3971 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-11-26 13:28:03.123  INFO 3971 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 65 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-11-26 13:28:03.467  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-11-26 13:28:03.840  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-11-26 13:28:03.890  INFO 3971 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-11-26 13:28:03.944  INFO 3971 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2021-11-26 13:28:04.098  INFO 3971 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-11-26 13:28:04.178  INFO 3971 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-11-26 13:28:04.627  INFO 3971 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-11-26 13:28:04.636  INFO 3971 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-26 13:28:05.013  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.shree.testjpa.TestJpaApplication     : Started TestJpaApplication in 7.64 seconds (JVM running for 8.112)
2021-11-26 13:28:05.134 DEBUG 3971 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        city0_.id as id1_0_,
        city0_.country_name as country_2_0_,
        city0_.name as name3_0_ 
    from
        city city0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        city0_.id as id1_0_,
        city0_.country_name as country_2_0_,
        city0_.name as name3_0_ 
    from
        city city0_
2021-11-26 13:28:05.198 DEBUG 3971 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        person
        (age, country_name, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        person
        (age, country_name, name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2021-11-26 13:28:05.200 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [25]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.200 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [India]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.201 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Shrirang]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.214 DEBUG 3971 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        person_city_company
        (person_id, country_name, city_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        person_city_company
        (person_id, country_name, city_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2021-11-26 13:28:05.215 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [16]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.215 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [India]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.215 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.215 TRACE 3971 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [India]
2021-11-26 13:28:05.218  INFO 3971 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-11-26 13:28:05.219  WARN 3971 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2021-11-26 13:28:05.219 ERROR 3971 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
2021-11-26 13:28:05.226  INFO 3971 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-26 13:28:05.247 ERROR 3971 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:751) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.shree.testjpa.TestJpaApplication.main(TestJpaApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not insert collection: [com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person.stayed#16]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert collection: [com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person.stayed#16]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.saveAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.shree.testjpa.TestService.initTables(TestService.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.shree.testjpa.TestJpaApplication.run(TestJpaApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert collection: [com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person.stayed#16]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1392) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1416) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3299) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2434) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1396) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1409) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1776) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:365) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1352) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.1.Final.jar:5.6.1.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2021-11-26 13:28:05.249  INFO 3971 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-11-26 13:28:05.251  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-11-26 13:28:05.263  INFO 3971 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I am suspecting issue is with mapping (List) I have in Person entity.

Note- findAll() call on Person repository working perfectly fine

Comment: please only post the relevant code/information. What is so difficult about this: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3)? you are passing more parameters then possible, or are using the indices wrong

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` it sure looks like you're passing an `id` into your constructors. Try not doing that.

Comment: You may also try not having `AUTO_INCREMENT` in your table definition. In that case, however, you will have to control the unique sequencing of `id` column in `Person` table.

Comment: @Stultuske I am not passing more parameter. Queries and prepared statements are generated by Spring framework

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am passing id as 0 so that code/db will generate appropriate id.

Comment: @SreeKumar This is just a sample code. In my actual code I am not allowed to change table definitions

Comment: OK. Is is possible to post the generated query that is giving the error as well? I couldn't spot in the post, I am sorry.

Comment: Why are you passing `cityLIst` - this is not part of your `Person` table. Maybe it should be marked as `@Transient`

Comment: @SreeKumar I have updated log (shown sqls). Sorry, IntelliJ was not showing queries somehow, run in eclipse

Comment: @ScaryWombat Person entity is having field "private List<City> stayed;"

Comment: But as it is not `@Transient` it is trying to insert into the DB *could not insert collection: [com.shree.testjpa.entity.Person.stayed*

Comment: I think it is trying to insert into `CITY` table because the passed `List<City>` for the field `Person.stayed`, while that field actually seems to be more for a **view** than for persistence. You should investigate the need for `Cascade.MERGE` on the JPA field `Person.stayed`.

Comment: @SreeKumar if you check the logs, you wont see any query which inserts into CITY. However the insert query is for that mapping table is not generted with field company_id(company_id is field of person_city_company, which is not there in query), I feel this is the reason of failure :  
    insert into
        person_city_company
        (person_id, country_name, city_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?).           -- I debugged source code and found that prepared statment is trying to set   company_id as well (which is index 4)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Not `CITY`, but `PERSON_CITY_COMPANY`, which has only three columns and each instance of `City` has 4.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I wanted to insert into person_city_company, which spring is doing (we we look at logs), But it is trying to set company_id with prepared stament

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are trying to add the primary key onto the entity, note since your using IDENTITY, spring will do that for you